# TextView from EditText animation like on LinkedIn

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, material-design

I want to know which ui view is used in Linkedin android application on login screen when you type in your username and password, the one where when you type, editText hint goes up as text view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Then you can use TextInputLayout from design library

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its called TextInputLayout.

Structure goes like this

```
<TextInputLayout>
<Edittext/>
</TextInputLayout>
```

Refer here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html